# Catch Exception and break (on exception) when executing code using IPython's magic for running cell

Tags: python, exception, ipython, jupyter

How do I catch errors, when the some python commands present in a Jupyter cell are being run using IPython's magick command?

```py
In [1]: from IPython import get_ipython
        from IPython.core.magics.namespace import NamespaceMagics
        from IPython.utils.capture import capture_output


In [2]: _nms = NamespaceMagics()
        _Jupyter = get_ipython()
        _nms.shell = _Jupyter.kernel.shell
        cell_capture = capture_output(stdout=True, stderr=True, display=True)

In [3]: cell = "y = z**2"

In [4]: with cell_capture:
            _nms.shell.run_cell(cell)
        
        print("This gets printed")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5330dcdc6092> in <module>
----> 1 y = z**2

NameError: name 'z' is not defined

This gets printed
```

Apart from using `exec` to run the cell, is there a way I can break on encountering the `NameError` (or any other `Exception` in general)?

**[EDIT]**:

I've already tried using `try....catch` (but it doesn't resolve that for me):

```py
In [5]: try:
            with cell_capture:
                _nms.shell.run_cell(cell)
        except Exception:
            raise

        print("Something here")


NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-5330dcdc6092> in <module>
----> 1 y = z**2

NameError: name 'z' is not defined

Something here
```

**EDIT 2**:

```py
try:
    with cell_capture:
        print('Inside cell capture here')
        _nms.shell.run_cell(cell)
except NameError:
    print("I'm in NameError")
    raise NameError("something bad happened")

print("Something here")


NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5330dcdc6092> in <module>
----> 1 y = z**2

NameError: name 'z' is not defined

Something here
```

Comment: `try: ... except NameError: ...`…?

Comment: That still doesn't do what I'm looking for, please see the **EDIT** mentioned in the Original Post

Comment: Well, you're just `raise`ing the exception again. Did you actually test whether it's caught in that `except` block or not?

Comment: No, it doesn't even reach that block of code inside `except`, that's one thing.

Comment: @deceze Please see the **EDIT 2** in original post

Answer (score 0):

The result of a call to InteractiveShell.run_cell() is an instance of an ExecutionResult. It has the method "raise_error" that "Reraises error if success is False, otherwise does nothing". You can catch the exception, process it, and reraise it (if needed).

```py
with cell_capture:
    result = get_ipython().run_cell(cell)
    result.raise_error()
```

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.ExecutionResult

Answer (score 0):

A note: `get_ipython()` and `get_ipython().kernel.shell` are the same object, so `get_ipython().run_cell(cell)` is the same as the longer chain:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell, ExecutionResult
ishell:InteractiveShell = get_ipython()
print(id(ishell), id(ishell.kernel.shell))
```

(Technically `get_ipython` will return `ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell` (Jupyter) or `google.colab._shell.Shell` (Colab), but they both extend `IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell`)

For me, this does not run past `shell.run_cell`:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell, ExecutionResult
from IPython.utils.capture import capture_output, CapturedIO
cell = 'print("hello world")\nraise ValueError("hello sun")'
shell:InteractiveShell = get_ipython()  # noqa `get_ipython` is present in notebooks
with capture_output(stdout=True, stderr=True, display=True) as captured: #: CapturedIO
    try:
        print('hello mercury')
        result:ExecutionResult = shell.run_cell(cell)
        print(captured.stdout)
        print(captured.stderr)
        print(captured.outputs)
    except Exception as error:
        print('hello world')
        print(type(error))
```

Because `capture_output` does not stop errors it just muffles them:

```
cell = 'print("hello world")\nraise ValueError("hello sun")'
shell:InteractiveShell = get_ipython()  # noqa `get_ipython` is present in notebooks
with capture_output(stdout=False, stderr=True, display=False) as captured: #: CapturedIO
    result:ExecutionResult = shell.run_cell(cell)
print('hello jupyter') # this is never run.
```

Therefore, the problem is something within `shell.run_cell`. Checking what this does:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(shell.run_cell)))
```

super up the mro to `InteractiveShell().run_cell`

```
print(inspect.getsource(InteractiveShell.run_cell))
```

gives:

```
    result = None
try:
    result = self._run_cell(
        raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
finally:
    self.events.trigger('post_execute')
    if not silent:
        self.events.trigger('post_run_cell', result)
return result
```

The triggers caught my eye... and for my applications at least (keeping track of errors), this works well at getting the error:

```
def foo(result: ExecutionResult):
    pass

shell.events.callbacks['post_run_cell'].append(foo)
```